# iOS show notification when something had happen in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a little bit confused if i have to do that,or the system :

Using the iBeacon there is a method that is fired when app is in background or closed.
There , i would like to write the code that will show the user a push notification on the iPhone home screen, to let him know about it .

How would i do such a simple thing ?

```
//happens in background when user inside a place 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    NSLog(@"***********************ENTER");

//here show notification !
```

Comment: Schedule a local notification.

Comment: how ? i know its simple, i just cant find it on google..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. This will schedule a local notification to fire at a set date and time (you need to provide the NSDate and message).

```
...
NSDate *fireDate =   // whatever date and time you want to fire the notification
NSString alertMessage = @“Alert message!";
[self addNotification:fireDate mymessage:alertMessage];
...


-(void)addNotification:(NSDate *)mydate mymessage:(NSString *)mymessage 
{
  UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = mydate;
    localNotification.alertBody = mymessage;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```